# Spring RestTemplate: How to serialize java.util.Collection

Tags: java, spring

I need to call a RESTful webservice from a Java program and pass it to a DateTime Collection.

So, my code is like the following:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
try {
    String scheme = request.getScheme();
    String userInfo = request.getRemoteUser();
    String host = request.getLocalAddr();
    int port = request.getLocalPort();
    String path = "/myapp/common/myapi";

    MultiValueMap<String, Object> requestParams = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>();

    requestParams.add("aId", objA.getId());
    requestParams.add("bIb", objB.getId());

    for (DateTime date : dates) {
        requestParams.add("dates", date);
    }

    URI apiUri = new URI(scheme, userInfo, host, port, path, null, null);
    result = restTemplate.postForObject(apiUri.toString(), request, BigDecimal.class,
            requestParams);
} catch (URISyntaxException e) {
    logger.error(e.getMessage());
} catch (DataAccessException e) {
    logger.error(e.getMessage());
}
```

And the webservice's signature is like:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "myapi", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody BigDecimal myApi(
        @RequestParam("dates") final List<DateTime> dates,
        @RequestParam("aId") final Integer aId, @RequestParam("bId") final Integer bId) {

    [...]

    return result;

}
```

But I get the error:

> org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: No serializer found for class java.util.Collections$3 and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) )

I understand that the problem is the serialization of the collection, but I do not know how to solve it.

**Updated**
I also tried with a Command class, so something like:

```
public class CalcolaGiorniResiduiCommand implements Serializable {
    private List<DateTime> dates;
    //[...]
}
```

Changed the controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "myapi", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody BigDecimal myApi(
        @RequestParam("command") final MyCommand command) {
```

And finally:

```
MyCommand command = MyCommand.build(1, 1, dates); //dates is a DateTime Collection
restTemplate.postForObject(apiUri.toString(), request, BigDecimal.class, command);
```

But I get the same error.

Any help, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html#postForObject-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Class-java.lang.Object...-), the request parameter is the Object to be POSTed, so the command object have to be passed as second parameter instead of the object request.

So the code should be changed from:

```
restTemplate.postForObject(apiUri.toString(), request, BigDecimal.class, command);
```

to:

```
restTemplate.postForObject(apiUri.toString(), command, BigDecimal.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I think you have to pass a list of dateTime object rather than adding it multiple time. Can you please try with the below snippet.
 List<DateTime> dates = new ArrayList<>();

 for (DateTime date : dates) {
        dates.add(date);
    }
requestParams.add("dates", dates);
```